# Copy rows that meet a date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]I want to be able to copy rows from a source sheet to a destination sheet that is the date in a range equals a target date.

I am using the following script and works perfectly when the target is a 'text', but as soon as I try to use a 'date' I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source'); //source sheet
   var testrange = sheet.getRange('F:F');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Destination'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in L:L; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'target') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,45).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

Thanks
Simon

Comment: How do you pick your target date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure what your target was so I assumed current date and proceeded anyway.  If it's wrong let me know.

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var csh=ss.getSheetByName('Destination');
  var found=false;
  var dt=new Date();
  var today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
  var output=[];
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var date=new Date(vA[i][4]);//can be a string the constructor recognizes or a date
    var dv=new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
    if (dv==today) {
      output.push(vA[i]);
      var found=true;
    }
  }
  if(found) {
    csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No matches');
  }
}
```

The following function will get those rows that have todays date and this email email1@test.com.

```
function copyrange(target) {
  var target=target||'email1@test.com';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var csh=ss.getSheetByName('Destination');
  var found=false;
  var dt=new Date();
  var today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
  var output=[];
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var date=new Date(vA[i][4]);//can be a string the constructor recognizes or a date
    var dv=new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
    if (dv==today && vA[i][6]==target) {
      output.push(vA[i]);
      var found=true;
    }
  }
  if(found) {
    csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No matches');
  }
}
```

And you can change the target email by passing an email to the function.

This function covers dates that have occurred in the last week:

```
function copyrange(target) {
  var target=target||'email1@test.com';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var csh=ss.getSheetByName('Destination');
  var found=false;
  var dt=new Date();
  var today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
  var sevendaysago=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-7).valueOf();//midnight
  var output=[];
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var date=new Date(vA[i][4]);//can be a string the constructor recognizes or a date
    var dv=new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
    if (dv>=sevendaysago && dv<=today && vA[i][6]==target) {
      output.push(vA[i]);
      var found=true;
    }
  }
  if(found) {
    csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No matches');
  }
}
```

This function only copies B and G of the matching row.

```
function copyrange(target) {
  var target=target||'email1@test.com';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var vA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var csh=ss.getSheetByName('Destination');
  var found=false;
  var dt=new Date();
  var today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
  var sevendaysago=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-7).valueOf();//midnight
  var output=[];
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var date=new Date(vA[i][4]);//can be a string the constructor recognizes or a date
    var dv=new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()).valueOf();//midnight
    if (dv>=sevendaysago && dv<=today && vA[i][6]==target) {
      output.push([vA[i][1],vA[6]]);
      var found=true;
    }
  }
  if(found) {
    csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No matches');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I tried to copy your code but got the same error. I added a screenshot of a sample sheet, maybe I didn't use you code correctly?.

Comment: Also, no need to be today's date it could be a date from a specific cell in the destination sheet, or even better, if I can build a range of start and finish date using 2 cells.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14r_ePmkUxVQQUgE6oavav4u8kbcuBRPn64eeInXOk3U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well the obvious problem is that column 6 or F is not a date.

Comment: Try it now.  I just tested it on my data and it works.

Comment: I guess that's the target you wanted.

Comment: can I ask you a couple more questions?. 1. How do I select specific rows to copy within the source column (instead of copy the entire column)?. 2. Is it to complicated to set a range of dates from date xx/xx/xxx to date xx/xx/xxx?

Comment: No it's not complicated.

Comment: :), should I ask in a separete question?, I am new to both scripts and stackoverflow

Comment: That's okay I've got several examples in there now.  Take a close look at them and open up the documentation.  The more you can figure out on your own the more comfortable you will get with the documentation and you will find yourself referring to it often.  I use it all of the time.

Comment: wow, thank you so much....just one more question...let say I only want to copy the column B and G of the matching row?.